# How to stack notifications in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification

I'm new to Android Development, I'm creating an app that receieves messages from a Server (using WebSockets) and I want to receive notifications when it sends a message. I did it and all works, the only thing that I would like is to have a single notification that can be expandex (like Gmail or WhatsApp one). I searched for the past two days but didn't find what i was looking for (also from Android Developers website). Can someone help me doing this? Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad english if you need clarifications for the problem just ask :)

Something like the phone pic here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html (Tried doing this but didn't worked.. I can post the code with it if you want to see)

Here is my code(UPDATED):

```
         int n=0;
         final static String GROUP = "group";
public void notifica(String title,String text) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icona)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                    .addLine(text)
                    .setBigContentTitle(n+" new messages")
                    .setSummaryText("irrigator"))
                    .setGroup(GROUP)
                    .setGroupSummary(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(text));

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(n, mBuilder.build());
}
n++;
```

UPDATE2:

```
 Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from a ")
            .setContentText("a")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icona)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
            .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(n, notif);
    n++;

    Notification notif2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from dsd" )
            .setContentText("td")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icona)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(n, notif2);
    n++;
```

Comment: What does "It didn't not work" mean? What result are you seeing? Secondly the first step is to set a group, you have not set a group.

Comment: I've updated the code, it just shows a new notification with the text every time I send a new message like before

Comment: You are assigning the same id to all your notifications. This will simply replace the previous one rather than adding a new one to the group.

Comment: I forgot to paste the n++; I updated the code

Comment: Where is this code? Is `n` really different on each notification, or does it get reset to 0 each time.

Comment: It changes every time(n++ every time I use the method ) but doing this makes different notifications

Comment: I see your issue now. You are creating multiple summary notifications, and not updating the content. You need to create non-summary notifications and ONE summary notification.

Comment: It says:"Later on, when you create another notification, specify the same group key. When you call notify(), this notification appears in the same stack as the previous notification, instead of as a new card" I tried creating 2 notifications but it creates 2 notifications.. I edited again see what i writed

Comment: try this github example.................https://gist.github.com/waynepiekarski/775dcd9105bd5c376eb4

Comment: Thank you. Will check it when I'm back home

Comment: Try removing `.setGroupSummary(true)`. That will at least give you the stacked notifications.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I realized that currently most devices(with exception of some wearables) don't support stacking so you'll have to do something manual. What I ended up doing is storing the count of notifications in SharedPrefs, and then updating the message when new notifications come up overwriting previous ones now with new title.
FCMService.java

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = Utils.getSharedPrefs(getApplicationContext());
int notificationCount = sharedPrefs.getInt("CURRENT_OUTSTANDING_NOTIFICATION_COUNT", 0);

notificationCount++;

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putInt("CURRENT_OUTSTANDING_NOTIFICATION_COUNT", notificationCount);
editor.commit();

if(notificationCount>1){
    messageTitle = notificationCount+" New Messages";
    messageText = "Last Message Content:"+ messageText;
}

//send notification with the new title and text
...
```

Then in the activity that reads your notifications just reset the counter, voila you're done.
NotificationViewActivity.java

```
//somewhere where notifications are read
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putInt("CURRENT_OUTSTANDING_NOTIFICATION_COUNT", 0);
editor.commit();
```